# Dynamically defined list

Tags: java, list

Hi I'm trying to make a simple program that prints out the elements 
of a list.The catch is that the list should be dynamically initialized from 
the console(the user must be able to input as much as elements he wants),and 
then the program has to print on the console.

I wrote this code,but it's giving me some errors at line 13:

### Error:

Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
- void is an invalid type for the variable-"keyPressed"
- Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

### Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

        void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            for(Integer i = 0;i < list.size();i++){
                i = (Integer) in.nextInt();
                list.add(i);
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to declare another method method in main? It looks like that.

Comment: You cannot have a method inside of another method in Java, move the "keyPressed" method, outside of your main.

Answer (score 0):

keyPressed method has to be defined outside the main method. Also, the body of your for loop won't be executed as the list is empty. You need to loop - "while" - until the user inputs the "KeyEvent.VK_ENTER" and then exit the loop and print the list.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do something like this instead of trying to capture each key press:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

        while(in.hasNextInt())
        {
            list.add(in.nextInt());
        }        

        System.out.println("Invalid integer entered.");
        System.out.println("List contents:");
        for(int i : list)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @andrewxxx NP.  Feel free to accept answer if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nextInt = in.nextInt();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(nextInt);
        for (int i = 0; i < nextInt; i++) {
            list.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
```

code to store and print value of dynamic length of list with dynamic value input